# getting a particular div in to view or scroll into view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a feature to my website in a way that when i click a link i want a particular div element to come in to view for a user.. ive tried the code

```
$(".testClick").live("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); 
      // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll("indID13");
});


 function goToByScroll(id){
      // Reove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

but this doesnt work... is it possible to achieve this feature with out any plugin by pure jquery itself.. or should i be using any plugin...
I will add a  sample of what ive tried. the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/xFu3M/

and try this one toooo http://jsfiddle.net/xFu3M/6/ is this a bug..im trying to get div 1 in to view and its already in view,, so when i click the link it shows some other div

Comment: `live` has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had a syntax error, change the .live to .on as the .live has depreciated in later versions of jQuery use this and it will work:

```
$(".testClick").on("click",function(e){...
```

See this edited fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFu3M/1/)

Comment: thanks that worked... :) wt if the dom is created dynamically and if im using .on inside document ready wrapper, the click event will nt b detected right?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".wrapper").css({"width" : $(window).width() , "height" :  $(window).height()});
        $(".testClick").on("click",function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            goToByScroll("indID13");
        });
    });

    function goToByScroll(id)
    {
        id = id.replace("link", "");
        $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
        },'slow');
    }

</script>
```

You click event code was not surrounded in `document.ready`.

Also use `.on` instead of `.live` because it already depreciated from now on.

Comment: wt if the dom is created dynamically and if im using .on inside document ready wrapper, the click event will nt b detected right?

Comment: not right, it will work... no matter if dom is dynamically created.